# Declare methods using arrow functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am going through FreeCodeCamp React exercises and there is one of [simple incrementing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/react/write-a-simple-counter) and decrementing a count value initialised on state.

If I write the methods using traditional functions, it works fine:

```
increment() {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count + 1
  });
}
decrement() {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count - 1
  });
}
reset() {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count = 0
  });
}
```

But if I use arrow functions, it simply stops working. Instead of reseting to zero, the "reset" button decrements the value the same way that "decrement" button does. "Increment" and "decrement" work apparently normal.

```
increment = () => {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count + 1
  });
} 
decrement = () => {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count - 1
  });
} 
reset = () => {
  this.setState({
    count: this.state.count = 0
  });
}
```

I am missing a detail here. Can some of the colleagues tell me why the function expression does not work in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can i get full code of your question?

Comment: why `count: this.state.count = 0` and not just `count: 0`?

Comment: @gnujoow, here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/raw/014DzXj2

Comment: @Apostolos: if I use 'count: 0' the system gives me an error messgae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function expressions are all suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors. Please examine this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions differ from regular functions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

In short, the value of 'this' is not the same in the regular function and the lambda function.

Just to add a little precision, you probably used .bind(), so, taken two functions (one regular and one arrow that returns this, and trying to bind them we get:

```
const f=function() { return this; };
const bf=f.bind({});
console.log(bf()); // correctly binds 'this' to the provided object

const l=()=>this;
const bl=l.bind({});
console.log(bl()); // didn't bind, returned window
```